# Why does code autocomplete not work for Jupyter notebooks in most IDEs (VSCode, PyCharm, or DataSpell)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm, ide, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to run R code in a Jupyter notebook. The code auto completion - for example, variable names appearing in a dropdown the moment I type `df$` - does not work at all in most IDEs. For some reason, this only works with JupyterLab. Is there something I am missing with IDE configuration?